# extract the key value from the map and use

Tags: json, go

I am trying to transform this JSON with Go:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "check_1": {
      "command": "script1.sh"
    },
    "check_2": {
      "command": "script2.sh"
    }
  }
}
```

To this format:

```
{
  "checks": [
    {
      "name": "check_1",
      "command": "script1.sh"
    },
    {
      "name": "check_2",
      "command": "script2.sh"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't find a way to do it right. Clarify that I recently started with Go and tried to do it with maps and structs.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What did you try? Show your code. What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/SMsX3vC_LNZ -- Note that maps in Go are by design unordered, so the resulting json array elements may not be in the same order as the original json object elements. If you need the exact order you could probably still do it with [Token](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.19.1#Decoder.Token), but that'd be definitely more involved.

Comment: If "check_1" and "check_2" are the only possibilities struct's would suffice. Otherwise you do need maps.